# passenger_base_uri not working on passenger 4.0.0rc4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, passenger

We are running `ruby 2.0.0-p0` with `passenger 4.0.0rc` (`nginx/1.2.7`) on `ubuntu 12.04` server in production (`rails 3.2.12`). Just notice that the `passenger_base_uri` in our nginx.conf is not pointing to the base subdir. Instead it return nothing. Here is `passenger_base_uri` in nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 154.49.55.6;
  root /ebs/www/;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  passenger_base_uri /nbhy;

  #for rails >= 3.1, assets pipeline
  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-control public;
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
}
```

A `symlink nbhy` was created on the server under /ebs/www and point to `/ebs/www/nbhyop/current/public`. The `/nbhy` is the base uri for rails app.

Here is the `nginx error log`,

```
[ 2013-05-06 17:47:00.5469 718/7f5097fc0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1098 ]: [App 838 stdout]
2013/05/06 17:47:26 [error] 735#0: *104 open() "/ebs/www/authentify/session" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 6.5.5.94, server: 154.49.55.6, request: "POST /authentify/session HTTP/1.1", host: "154.49.55.6", referrer: "http://154.49.55.6/nbhy/signin"
```

The path above should be: /ebs/www/nbhy/authentify/session instead of /ebs/www/authentify/session.

The same config is working on passenger 3.x. How to fix this problem?  Thanks for help

Comment: Without diving too deep, have you tried updating to [4.0.1](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/05/06/phusion-passenger-4-0-1-final-release/)? It was released today.

Comment: I just saw the news about 4.0.1 and is thinking about it. But this is a basic feature and not sure how it happened. Or could be some other problem?

Comment: upgraded to passenger 4.0.1 and the problem is the same.

Comment: I've recorded this issue as a bug. Work is on the way to fix this. https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=878

Comment: Thanks for the followup. Please let me know if there is some finding. This sub uri problem is still bothering us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were using passenger_base_uri for the wrong purpose. By specifying passenger_base_uri, you are saying:

"I have another web app, living under /nbhy"

I see in the Nginx output that you were doing a POST /authentify/session. Since you are not accessing any URL under /nbhy, the passenger_base_uri option has no effect. If you POST /nbhy/authentify/session, then it'll have effect.

Perhaps you want to set the virtual host's root to /ebs/www/nbhyop/current/public?

Comment: under /nbhy, there is only one app. The document root is /ebs/www/. All apps go under this /ebs/www/. Our purpose is to host multiple rails apps on the same server. Each app can be accessed by myip.com/app_name.

Comment: Here is our another post about the same issue. It was suggested that we need to add sub uri in front of the path in code. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532188/404-not-found-error-in-deploying-rails-3-2-12-app-with-engines-to-sub-uri-on-n

Comment: Just mark the post as answer which does not solve the issue but getting us closer.