# 404 Not Found error in deploying rails 3.2.12 app (with engines) to SUB URI on nginx/passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

We need to deploy a `rails 3.2.12 app` to `sub uri nbhy` on a `ubuntu 12.04` server. The `rails app` has 3 `engines` and one of them is `authentify` which is for user authentication. The main app's root pointing to authentify's signin page. Here is the routes.rb in main app:

```
  root :to => "authentify::sessions#new"
  match '/signin',  :to => 'authentify::sessions#new'
  match '/signout', :to => 'authentify::sessions#destroy'
  match '/user_menus', :to => 'user_menus#index'
  match '/view_handler', :to => 'authentify::application#view_handler'
```

The app is deployed to base uri `nbhy` running on `ubuntu 12.04` with `passenger and nginx`.  On the same server, there is another rails app running in its own sub uri. Here is the configuration in nginx.conf for `sub uri nbhy`:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 6.95.225.93;
   root /var/www/;
   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_env production;
   passenger_base_uri /by;
   passenger_base_uri /nbhy;

   #for rails >=3.1, assets pipeline
   location ~ ^/assets/ {
     expires max;
     add_header Cache-Control public;
     add_header ETag "";
     break;
   }
}
```

Also a `symlink` `nbhy` is created at `document root` `/var/www` pointing to `/var/www/nbhyop/current/public`. Here is the output of the `root /var/www/`:

```
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cjadmin www-data   28 Nov  3  2012 by -> /var/www/byop/current/public
drwxrwsr-x 4 cjadmin www-data 4096 Nov  4  2012 byop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cjadmin www-data   30 May 16 21:27 nbhy -> /var/www/nbhyop/current/public
drwxrwsr-x 4 cjadmin www-data 4096 May 14 15:21 nbhyop
```

The `by` is the `first` rails app deployed to the `sub URI` and is working fine.

The `login page` is displayed after typing `http://6.95.225.93/nbhy`. After key in user and password, the page was redirected to `http://6.95.225.93/authentify/session` with `404 Not Found` error. There is an error found in `nginx` `error.log`:

```
2013/05/13 16:29:25 [error] 2384#0: *1 open() "/var/www/authentify/session" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.1, server: 6.95.225.93, request: "POST /authentify/session HTTP/1.1", host: "6.95.225.93", referrer: "http://6.95.225.93/nbhy/"
```

Obviously `/var/www/authentify/session` will not hit the right page because it is missing the `base uri` `nbhy` between `www` and `authentify`. Based on our analysis, the `create` in `authentify session controller` hasn't been hit and the user hasn't been authenticated even with the right user name and password at `http://6.95.225.93/nbhy`.

Also find out that a user can `login` at `http://6.95.225.93/nbhy/authentify/session/new` with some twist. After login the page will be redirected to `http://6.95.225.93/user_menus` which will throw out `404 Not Found` error. However if we insert `nbhy` in between as : `http://6.95.225.93/nbhy/user_menus`, then it will bring up the `user menus page` successfully. For any further click on links, manually inserting `nbhy` will make the link work (if `nbhy` is missing).

The rails app worked fine when deploying without `sub uri`.

Why the sub uri is missing from route? Is there a way we can make the `nbhy` here to stay and eliminate the error? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the `authentify` engine is doing a redirect to `/user_menus`, instead of `/nbhy/authentify`. Is this a custom Rails or Sinatra app that you have written? If so, you need to change/configure the code of `authentify` to always append the current subdirectory under which the Rails app is hosted. You can get that from passenger by saying `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']` in your code.

Comment: redirect_to '/user_menus' . You are right. After a user is authorized, the authentify is redirect to /user_menus as above. Can we do: redirect_to ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']+'/user_menus'? Is the line above OK in development?

Comment: Also do we need to put this relative url root in every redirect in the app? We still don't quite understand why the last 2 deployment to sub uri are working fine (just with the config in nginx.conf and symlink like above) and this one with engines is getting so difficulty.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, you need to use `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] + '/user/menus'`. If you're using the Rails path helpers (like `user_path`, `login_path`, etc) then you have no problem, they will automatically append the relative URL root. But if you're doing your own redirect to a custom path, then you need to do this yourself.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a helper function like `def redirect_relative_to`, which appends the `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']` automatically if the given URL starts with `/`. And then you could use this function everywhere instead of the normal `redirect_to`.

Comment: There is a constant SUBURI defined in the app which is equal to '/nbhy' for production and '' for development/test. SUBURI is prefixed to the url. In previous deployment, we notice that there is no need to prefix SUBURI to regular path such as users_path. SUBURI is only needed for custom route. Is this still true in this deployment? (we do not know whole lot about routing in rails).

Comment: If changing to redirec_to user_menus_path, can we go by without prefixing SUBURI /nbhy? Our experience is no. But we don't quite understand why not as user_menus_path is a regular path. We thought if first redirect_to has the SUBURI prefixed, then this suburi will be carried along in following routing/redirect. Obviously this is not right and we don't quite understand why.

Comment: After prefix with SUBURI to routes in main app, the links start working, except the login page (on http://6.95.225.93/nbhy). Is there a way http://6.95.225.93/nbhy pointing to nbhy/authentify/signin automatically so the login will not have error?

Comment: When compiling assets, just do bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=/nbhy

Answer (score 1):

Rails is generating paths straight from `http://6.95.225.93` instead of `http://6.95.225.93/nbhy`.

You probably need to scope all your routes to "/nbhy".

**config/routes.rb**

```
scope "/nbhy" do
  ...
end
```

Comment: Will try scope again. Also do we need to keep current config in nginx and symlink?

Comment: One more question about scope in routes.rb: How to handle the route in development for no nbhy? Can we do scope "/nbhy" || "/" do?

Comment: With sope '/nbhy' do, the user menus page shows up with http://6.95.225.93/nbhy/nbhy/user_menus after manually inserting one extra /nbhy. We can login at http://6.95.225.93/nbhy/nbhy/authentify/session/new. It seems having the same routing behavior without scope.