# How to use sub uri to login in rails 3.2.12 with passenger/nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Our Rails 3.2.12 app is hosted under subdirectory `/nbhy`. The `routes.rb` is (related only):

```
  root :to => "authentify::sessions#new"
  match '/signin',  :to => 'authentify::sessions#new'
  match '/signout', :to => 'authentify::sessions#destroy'
```

Here `authentify` is the rails engine which handles user authentication. Here is the `routes.rb` in engine `authentify`:

```
  resource :session
  root :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'
```

In order to login we have to use the link:

```
http://mysite.com/nbhy/authentify/session/new
```

But this link is too long and not easy to remember. If we login at:

```
http://mysite.com/nbhy
```

The system will throw out error 404 Not Found and redirect page to:

```
http://mysite.com/authentify/session
```

The problem is that the app is redirecting the login request to `/authentify/session` which can not be found (missing nbhy). Why nbhy is missing and how can we put it back in url so user can login from `http://mysite.com/nbhy`?

Here is the `nginx config` on `ubuntu 12.04 server` for the `sub uri`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com;
        root /var/www/;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        passenger_base_uri /nbhy;
}
```

Comment: Hi, is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532188/404-not-found-error-in-deploying-rails-3-2-12-app-with-engines-to-sub-uri-on-n

Comment: Yes, one of them. All the rest solved except this login url which is too long(.../nbhy/authentify/signin or nbhy/authentify/session/new).

Comment: Can you change the routes of the authentify engine ?

Comment: Yes, we can change the routes in engine authentify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
namespace :nbhy do
    match '/signin',  :to => 'authentify::sessions#new', :as => "signin"
    match '/signout', :to => 'authentify::sessions#destroy', :as => "signout"

    root :to => "signin"
end
```

And remove the base uri from passenger.

### Alternatively

You can change the server root:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;
    root /var/www/nbhy;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
}
```

Which  is very acceptable and thats what I do in all of my websites. bacuse it connectes between the domain and the root path.

Than all of your rotes are normal.

Comment: Tried scope before and it did not work. Is the name space and scope similar?

Comment: Here is our previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532188/404-not-found-error-in-deploying-rails-3-2-12-app-with-engines-to-sub-uri-on-n. Do we need to remove every SUBURI added in order to use namespace?